# Encypt file using PGP utilising powershell

Tags: powershell, gnupg

I am trying to encrypt multiple files in the folder, however it will not working if more than one files the **filepath** folder. If it only one file exist in the folder, it will encrypt without any issue. The following if the code that I have so far. Any advise what did I missed. Thanks

```
#region Encrypt
function Encrypt()
{
    $pgp_program = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}" + "\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
    
    $recipient = "PROD_20"
    $filepath = "C:\filesToEncypt\"
    
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath -recurse
    
    try
    {
        foreach ($item in $files)
        {
            try
            {
                write-host $item
                Start-Process $pgp_program -ArgumentList "--always-trust -r $recipient -e $item"
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        exit 1
    }
}
Encrypt
```

Comment: Maybe add `-File` to `Get-ChildItem` so it only actually returns `$files` and not folders. On the other hand, are you looking to encrypt the files in a separate process (if not, there is no need to `Start-Process`).

Comment: thanks Santiago. When I display Item using this command Write-host $files it display all files.

Comment: I assume you're not getting any errors then, and this is likely because you're using `Start-Process`. Try changing the `Start-Process` line for this: `& $pgp_program --always-trust -r $recipient -e $item`